# How to stop airflow running in docker?

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I followed  [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/start/docker.html) guide to start airflow with docker-compose. However, I cannot bring it down gracefully. The containers keep running. When I try to stop/kill them I get a permission denied error, even when run as sudo.

```
sudo docker container stop $(docker ps -q)
>>>
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: f5949450056b: Cannot kill container f5949450056b850da78e9485e27765bfa088fd9e182ee621866c684a30239445: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 2a051877d204: Cannot kill container 2a051877d2046c212d3405ad39b09112613a2b56c5a350e823991c0e07650460: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 226b5e46010d: Cannot kill container 226b5e46010d4aff63941624deb0afc5aeca01826decf93ea4969f333d2e9d5c: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 09385b720d31: Cannot kill container 09385b720d3110d0511504839f0f3dc03ae122832a8b162b75c886c6e0a4d3e5: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 6cd9b8213531: Cannot kill container 6cd9b821353175e7416859f8fac2910ff499a94d581741fbdc7cce24d43cebc9: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: 602eec1a9b1b: Cannot kill container 602eec1a9b1bb0c7134ca95663695b20572e3d4d7f42d9e22158001134b6d02b: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

running on Ubuntu 20.04.

The only solution I found so far is to enter each container with `docker exec -it ... bash` and run `kill 1`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html), you should use:

```
docker-compose down --volumes --rmi all
```

Comment: I used the command `docker-compose down` and it automatically stopped all airflow related containers

Answer (score 0):

I had to run

```
sudo aa-remove-unknown
```

to be able to stop the docker process.

Answer (score -1):

You go to the directory where your `docker-compose.yaml` file is located that you used to start your docker services. There you type:

```
sudo docker-compose stop
```

It's as simple as that!